# Is there a VS Code shortcut to move/select up/down to the next empty line?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just transitioned from Sublime to VS Code and love it. Wondering if there are equivalent combos, or a way to set them, for jumping/selecting chunks of line, down/up to the next blank line. This is what these looked like for me in ST3:

```
{"keys": ["ctrl+shift+["], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "stops", "empty_line": true, "forward": false, "extend": true}},
{"keys": ["ctrl+shift+]"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "stops", "empty_line": true, "forward": true, "extend": true}},
{"keys": ["ctrl+{"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "stops", "empty_line": true, "forward": false, "extend": true}},
{"keys": ["ctrl+}"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "stops", "empty_line": true, "forward": true, "extend": true}},
```

Answer (score 20):

This is in Stable v1.54 without an extension.  `prevBlankLine` and `nextBlankLine` `to` values have been added to the `cursorMove` command.  See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/115578.

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+[",    // whatever keybinding you want
    "command": "cursorMove",
    "args": {
        "to": "prevBlankLine",
        "select": true         // false is the default if omitted
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+]",
    "command": "cursorMove",
    "args": {
        "to": "nextBlankLine",
        "select": true         // false is the default if omitted
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
```

Comment: And of course add copies of above without the `+shift` where either `"select": false` or the `select` lines are taken out.

Comment: Thanks! Although I generally prefer pure commands as provided by plugins, as you can find them in the command list and bind them with the GUI keyboard shortcut editor, it's good to have a native solution.

Comment: Is this an API thing?
I don't see hot to bind this to a keyboard shortcut

Comment: @BradKent Sort of, `cursorMove` is a "complex command" (see https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands).  These do not show up in the Keyboard Shortcuts, presumably because they take arguments.

Comment: @Mark Thanks.  I found where to add these to keybindings.json

Answer (score 8):

[The following plugin meets your requirments I believe](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sashaweiss.block-travel)

Quote from plugin description

> Travel in a text editor by jumping over code "paragraphs", to the closest empty line, optionally selecting text along the way.
>
> The following commands and corresponding default keybindings are provided:

```
block-travel.jumpUp: alt+up
block-travel.selectUp: alt+shift+up
block-travel.jumpDown: alt+down
block-travel.selectDown: alt+shift+down
```

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: This is the second answer you have posted recommending this plugin. **You must disclose your affiliation, if any!** Also, please don't just post a tool as an answer as mentioned. Add more context. What if the linked page changes?

Comment: I have no affiliation, does that explain better?