# (Python) cursor jumps to the end of a function

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Python doesn't use `{}` to enclose a function, resulting that it's hard to move the cursor to the end of a function.

For example, in visual studio code (Mac), we could use `command + shift + \` to go from `{ to }` and `} to {`.

Have googled a lot but not yet found a good way, thanks.

Comment: I ended up using the shortcut for moving to the next/previous empty line https://stackoverflow.com/a/66066852/10710682. I really hope this feature is implemented in VSCode or as an extension.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `{` and `}` jump with code blocks via a vim plugin sample
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim

Answer (score 0):

[VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) is not my preferred editor and I don't use Mac, so I have no idea if it supports such a hotkey for Python on that OS. I use [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) on Win10, which per [it's default hotkey layout](https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/pycharm/docs/PyCharm_ReferenceCard.pdf) has `Ctrl + ]` to jump to the end of a code block. It works for jumping to the end of a function so long as your whitespace is correct throughout and your cursor is on a line that starts on the outermost indent of the function's scope. If it is on an inner indented line (like in a loop or context manager) then it jumps to the end of that indented block.

Edit: Just found [the mac keybindings for PyCharm](https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/pycharm/docs/PyCharm_ReferenceCard_mac.pdf?_ga=2.8059382.53751788.1611376753-668378262.1610921264). On that OS the hot key for jumping to an end of a block is `⌥ ⌘ ]` whatever the heck that is.