# Is there a "Jump to prev/next block" keyboard shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I am looking for a keyboard shortcut in VS Code that I miss from my 1980s source code editor (Turbo Pascal): moving the cursor forward or back one block of code at a time.

Given source code like following example:

```
/* My program */

int a()
{
    /* something */
}

int b()
{
    /* something */

    /* something else */
}

/* more */
```

I am looking for a keyboard shortcut that will let me jump to the previous or next block of code. Ideally, a *block* would be a logical unit of code, such as functions a() and b() in the example: from the top of the code, jump to the top of function a(), then to the top of function b(), and so on, and the same when jumping from the end of the code to the previous block.

If this does not exist, at least a jump to the next blank line would also help. In the above example this would include the jumps as described above, plus a jump to the blank line between the two comments in function b().

Is there a keyboard shortcut in VS Code that does either of these two kinds of jumps?

Comment: I don't think there is a built-in command to jump to the next block.  I see there are extensions that act as block jumpers (search for `jump block` in the Extensions input box) but they are jumping to the next/previous blank line (not trying to find actual parsed blocks of code).  But see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66066852/836330 - you don't an extension to do that anymore - there is a command available for jumping to the next/previous blank line.