# How to skip empty lines but not blocks in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like a keybinding command to move cursor to next non empty line.
For example:

```
msg = "Hello World"


print(msg)
```

Move the cursor between these lines skipping the empty lines in between.

Comment: related but not exactly what you asked for: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10093, which points to https://github.com/sashaweiss/vscode_block_travel and https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jmfirth.vsc-space-block-jumper (from googling "`github vscode issues keyboard shortcut move cursor skip empty lines`"). Also finds https://stackoverflow.com/q/45788119/11107541

Comment: Have already checked them. I am pretty sure that there is no post solving what I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an extension for that.  I assume that other "jumping" extensions can do it but here is an extension I wrote, [Jump and select](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.jump-and-select), for which you can set up a couple of keybindings (in your `keybindings.json`) like so:

```json
{
  "key": "alt+down",          // whatever keybindings you want
  "command": "jump-and-select.jumpForward",
  "args": {

                                  // go to next/previous line that isn't empty
    "text": "^.",                 // <== can use strings or regexp's here
  }
},

{
  "key": "alt+up",
  "command": "jump-and-select.jumpBackward",
  "args": {

    "text": "^.",
    // "text": "#\\d+\n"           //  double-escaped where necessary                                             
  }
}
```